# Frog in the Well

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, probability

A frog is trapped in a well, just 1 meter below the lip. On sunny days, the well is dry, and the frog is able to climb up 1 meter. On rainy days, the well is wet and the frog slides down 1 meter. If it is rainy 2 out of every 3 days and the well is infinitely deep, what are the frog's chances of ever reaching the lip and escaping?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an example of the

> [Gambler's ruin problem](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-GRP.pdf). Here, we consider "escaping the well" as the equivalent of becoming bankrupt, and "never escaping" as the equivalent of becoming infinitely rich.

Using that,

> The probability is $p = \frac{2}{3}$ and starting position $i=1$. We plug this in the formula of $1 - \Big(\frac{1-p}{p}\Big)^i = 1 - \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{2}{3}} = \boxed{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Haven't seen this version of the problem before, nice! To me it's a neat paradox that the frog has a chance of never escaping, but will never have no chance of escaping.

Comment: I just spent about 30 minutes writing out the P(x) equations for each meter and doing a convergence sum. I was about to post my answer and then I saw this and how simple it was lol

Comment: @Ankit, The solution you mentioned is included in the proof, so you are doing the right way. It is just that it already has a name (I was not familiar with this name before, too)

Comment: @justhalf Lol yeah I got 1/2 as well, I'm just saying that I spent so much time on a problem that takes 2 minutes lol.

Comment: I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around this. How could it be that there's a 50% chance the frog won't escape when the only way the situation ends is when the frog escapes? The situation should theoretically go on forever *until the frog escapes*, why is there ever a chance the frog won't escape?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins Yes, it may seem a bit paradoxical, but if the probability of something happening is large enough, the long-term probabilities of events can approach zero. You can imagine this situation: Suppose you are gambling and each round you spend a dollar. Now suppose you start with 100, and suppose you have a 99.99% chance of winning 1,000,000 in a game, and 0.01% chance of losing the 1 dollar you spent. If you play infinitely, sure, there's always "a chance" of going broke, but the limit of that event happening approaches zero as you play forever.

Comment: @sedrick Does that mean the probability that the frog makes it out ***approaches*** 50%?